# Using a previously used username that is no longer in use for my new Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, username

Facebook will not allow me to use "godjhavoc" as my username for my Facebook page.

The thing is, that username is no longer in use so I don't understand why Facebook won't let me use it.

Previously I used "godjhavoc" as my username for my personal page but I changed it to "ibraheempedro" so I figured "godjhavoc" would be available but it is not.

How do I use "godjhavoc" as my username for my Facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that Facebook is using some kind of delay to avoid fraud or irritations by overtaken usernames.

I see two possible ways (but I am not sure about their likelyness to be successful):

1. Wait some hours, days, weeks until this delay is over (but it might also well be that somewhen taken usernames are never given free anymore).
2. Write a mail to the [facebook support](https://www.facebook.com/help/) and ask them to deblock the specific username (but it might well be that facebook support employees can not manually influence the mechanisms of username restrictions).

Comment: Did my answer help?